# How do i use a static method from Form1 in a new class?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 in the top i added a bool variable in the constructor set it to false.
Then in a button click event i set it to true:

```
private void DriverVerifier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to Launch the Driver Verifier. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                verifier = false;
            }
            else
            {
                verifier = true;
                verifiers(verifier);
                ProcessRun.Processing(Environment.SystemDirectory, "verifier.exe", "", false, "");
            }

        }
```

Then in the bottom i created the verifiers method:

```
public static bool verifiers(bool verify)
        {

            return verify;
        }
```

Then in the new class i did:

```
if (Form1.verifiers(
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
   SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
```

But when i did Form1.verifiers in the new class its asking for a bool variable .
What i wanted to do is only to check if the method from form1 verifiers is true or false.

What should i do now ?

Comment: The code block starting with if (Form1.verifiers( is syntactically incoorect. Please provide the correct code of this method call in the if statement.

Comment: 1. Why static, if its verifying the form then it probably needs form information. 2. Your verify method just returns whatever youpass in?

Answer (score 0):

The `verifiers` method expects a `bool` parameter so you will have to provide one:

```
bool verifier = true;
if (Form1.verifiers(verifier))
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
}
```

***or*** rewrite it so that it accepts no parameters or provide a parameterless overload:

```
public static bool verifiers()
{
    ...
    return verify;
}

...

if (Form1.verifiers())
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing .. we can use static method by referring it with the class name

So I would prefere if you make a new class where you have static method Verifier

And then you can call it from your application by Class1.Verifier()

By putting it in the other class you will get the advantage of changing the behavior of the method without changing the Form1 class

I think this would help you to put your method and use it in the propr way...

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
if (Form1.verifiers(
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
   SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
```

Was meant to be:

```
if (Form1.verifiers())
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
   SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
}
```

In which case you need to change the constructor of your static method to be:

```
public static bool verifiers()
```